# PowerPoint Web Add-in (Export Slides To Image And Video) With Javascript API

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I am creating a PowerPoint Web Add-in plugin to publish presentation (All ppt slides) to the server as an image and video format. 
Is there any javascript API (office.js) for this?

Thanks.

Comment: was this ever achieved? If so, can you please let me know how you did this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no API in Office.js to do that. But a PowerPoint deck can be configured in PowerPoint to run automatically. It doesn't need to be in a video format. See [Create a self-running presentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-self-running-presentation-57fc41ae-f36a-4fb5-94a3-52d5bc466037?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fCreate-a-self-running-presentation-3CAF0CEF-7CDA-40F1-AB7A-F161A1A91D93&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Thank you @Rick for your input here. But I think Arjun is asking about the API to export the current open presentation as a video file. (Now only 2 options are available - Office.FileType.Compressed, Office.FileType.Pdf.  
But this was possible to do easily in VSTO add-ins.. as we had Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint there . (C#)